# How to pass the bound property with command to modify it

Tags: xamarin, freshmvvm

i have a page with multiple labels that each have a different property bound to it and when tapped open up a prompt to modify their value. I can't figure out how to pass that property with the command so i can modify it and use this same command for all labels.

In ContentPage:

```
                <Label x:Name="lblLevel" Text="{Binding Level}" FontSize="Large">
                    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer
                            Command="{Binding InputPopup}"
                            CommandParameter="{Binding Source={x:Reference lblLevel}, Path=Text}" />
                    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                </Label>
```

Command:

```
    public ICommand InputPopup => new Command(
        async () => {
            PromptResult pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig
            {
                InputType = InputType.Name,
                OkText = "Confirm",
                Title = "New value",
                CancelText = "Cancel",
                MaxLength = 1,
            });
            if (pResult.Ok && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pResult.Text))
            {
//Todo: PropertyX (Level) = pResult.Text
            }

        }
    );
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after trying a couple different things that i couldn't get to work i ended up using a switch, it's not pretty but atleast it works.

Command (in FreshMVVM ViewModel):

```
public ICommand EditValuePopupCommand => new Command<string>(
    async (param) =>
    {
        PromptResult pResult = await UserDialogs.Instance.PromptAsync(new PromptConfig
        {
            InputType = InputType.Name,
            OkText = "Confirm",
            Title = $"Edit {param}",
            CancelText = "Cancel",
            MaxLength = 2,
        });
        if (pResult.Ok && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(pResult.Text))
        {
            switch (param)
            {
                case "Level": Level = int.Parse(pResult.Text); break;
                case "Strength": Strength = "Str: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "Dexterity": Dexterity = "Dex: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "Constitution": Constitution = "Con: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "Wisdom": Wisdom = "Wis: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "Intelligence": Intelligence = "Int: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "Charisma": Charisma = "Cha: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "AttackModifier": AttackModifier = "Attack: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "SpellAttackModifier": SpellAttackModifier = "Spell Attack: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "SecondaryAttackModifier": SecondaryAttackModifier = "Second Attack: " + pResult.Text; break;
                case "SaveDC": SaveDC = "Second Attack: " + pResult.Text; break;

                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Default case");
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
);
```

XAML:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                    <Frame Style="{StaticResource DefaultFrameStyle}">
                        <Label x:Name="lblStrength" Text="{Binding Strength}">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Command="{Binding EditValuePopupCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="Strength" />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame Style="{StaticResource DefaultFrameStyle}">
                        <Label x:Name="lblDexterity" Text="{Binding Dexterity}">
                            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                                <TapGestureRecognizer
                                    Command="{Binding EditValuePopupCommand}"
                                    CommandParameter="Dexterity" />
                            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
                        </Label>
                    </Frame>
```

Answer (score 1):

just bind the `CommandParameter` to the same property as the `Label`

```
Command="{Binding InputPopup}"
CommandParameter="{Binding Level}"  />
```

Comment: Alright and how do i now use that CommandParameter and fill it's property with pResult.Text? Because i'd like to use the same command for other labels and properties as well.

Comment: Do you want to display the result in the Label?

Comment: I assume you could just assign the pResult to the command parameter - I've never tried that.  Note that if you want InputPopup to accept a string parameter, you should use `Command<string>`.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding#using-command-parameters

Comment: Yeah assigning the pResult to the command parameter is what i'd like to do but i don't know how and can't find any examples of it. It seems silly to use a seperate command for each label.

Comment: if you are passing the parameter using `Command<string>` you should be able to assign to the string property.  I don't know if this actually works, but that's what I would do.  Alternately, just use a click handler instead of a command